# iOS Swift keyCommands Reading Numbers Only

Tags: ios, swift, uikeycommand

Please consider the following code:

```
override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
    var commands:[UIKeyCommand] = []

    let numbers = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
    for number in numbers {
        let txt = number as String
        commands.append(UIKeyCommand(input: txt, modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(keyPressed(_:))))
    }
    commands.append(UIKeyCommand(input: "\r", modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(enterPressed)))
    return commands
}
```

For some reason only the numbers are getting read.  This is for a bluetooth barcode scanner that emulates a keyboard.  Is keyCommands not capable of reading alpha characters or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does the barcode contain lowercase letters?

Comment: Nope. All uppercase.  I even tried making the array just contain an X (a value in my test barcode) and it still didn't read it.

Comment: Is there somewhere you are setting the UIKeyboardType to an all numeric keyboard?

Comment: I see there's a [Shift modifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyCommand_class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIKeyModifierFlags). It makes me think you may have to use lowercase letters + the modifier to get the uppercase ones.

Comment: The Shift modifier was the answer.  Thanks!  I had to leave the letters as uppercase but it all works now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Eric Aya I was able to get this working.  Below is my modified code.  It may not be the most elegant solution but it works:

```
 override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
    var commands:[UIKeyCommand] = []

    let numbers = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]

    for number in numbers {
        let txt = number as String
        if Int(txt) == nil {
            commands.append(UIKeyCommand(input: txt, modifierFlags: [UIKeyModifierFlags.Shift], action: #selector(keyPressed(_:))))
        } else {
            commands.append(UIKeyCommand(input: txt, modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(keyPressed(_:))))
        }
    }
    commands.append(UIKeyCommand(input: "\r", modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(enterPressed)))
    return commands
}
```